# Downloaded png image becomes black/white

Tags: browser, images, transparency

Image from there:
https://account.gopay.com/captcha.img

Looks like this:
[image]

But when I download and open it, it looks like this:
[image]

Why does that happen?

Comment: Download into a different App and see if this is the App or the download (less likely)

Comment: Aren't both Black and White? (I understand that they are different pictures, but in your title you wrote that the issue is that they become black and white.)

Comment: Also, can you describe which browser you use and then he exact steps you're taking to "download" it? Because it looks like your 2nd one is also very pixelated unlike the original (and unlike what I get when downloading it)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the downloaded image is something else from what you see when you loaded the image in a browser is simple. That "image URL" isn't a specific image every time it's pulled from the server it gives a different image (it's for the Captcha service, where each Captcha to solve needs to be different.)

It doesn't only change when downloading, it also changes when you reload the page.

What you can do is, that instead of "downloading" the URL, you can do "Copy image" from the browser which will give you what you see.

Comment: Given that the title says "becomes black and white" I doubt they talk about the fact that different letters are displayed, but more about wrong alpha channel display

Comment: Possible, I'll wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: @YisroelTech like LPChip mentioned, I wasn't taking about that the letters are different (I should have used the same image), but the difference about colors